# Importing from AS400 to CSV using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, csv, vba

I am trying to export data from an AS400 table/file directly to a CSV File using Excel VBA. So far I have the following but it writes the output to the CSV file line by line and the headers do not seem to be included in the output.

I can output the data to Excel and save it as a CSV, but as it exceeds 1 million rows I only end up with half of what is required.

**How to bulk dump the data into CSV and include the headers?**

```
Sub ExportCSV()

 Set Conn = CreateObject("adodb.connection")
 Set rcd = CreateObject("adodb.recordset")
 Set outFile = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile("H:\myFile.csv")
 cnnstr = "DRIVER={Client Access ODBC Driver (32-bit)};SYSTEM=TEST;USERID=123;PWD=123"

 Conn.Open cnnstr

 Set rcd.ActiveConnection = Conn

 sqlstm = "SELECT TEST50,LTEST50 FROM TESTLIB.TEST Where TEST50 Is Not NULL And LTEST50 Is Not NULL Order By TEST50 ASC "

 rcd.Open sqlstm

 rcd.MoveFirst

Do
  outFile.WriteLine rcd("TEST50") & "," & rcd("LTEST50")
  rcd.MoveNext

Loop Until rcd.EOF

  rcd.Close
  con.Close

 Set rcd = Nothing
 Set Conn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: For your headers, you can do this before the `Do` loop: `outFile.WriteLine "Test50,LTest50"`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a brute force approach, I am certain there are more elegant ways to load large text files in to Excel, such as the one that Chip Pearson put together:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ImportBigFiles.aspx

Otherwise, brute force approach could get you started:

```
Sub ExportCSV()

 Dim wb as Object 'Excel.Workbook
 Dim ws as Object 'Excel.Worksheet
 Dim r As Long    'row counter/iterator

 Set Conn = CreateObject("adodb.connection")
 Set rcd = CreateObject("adodb.recordset")
 Set outFile = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile("H:\myFile.csv")
 cnnstr = "DRIVER={Client Access ODBC Driver (32-bit)};SYSTEM=TEST;USERID=123;PWD=123"

 Conn.Open cnnstr

 Set rcd.ActiveConnection = Conn

 sqlstm = "SELECT TEST50,LTEST50 FROM TESTLIB.TEST Where TEST50 Is Not NULL And LTEST50 Is Not NULL Order By TEST50 ASC "

 rcd.Open sqlstm

 rcd.MoveFirst

 'Create a new/empty Excel file
 Set wb = CreateExcelFile()
 Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1) 
 r = 1
 'write the headers
 Call WriteData(ws, r, "TEST50,LTEST50")

 'Write the data
 Do
    If Not r > ws.Rows.Count Then
        Call WriteData(ws, r, rcd("TEST50") & "," & rcd("LTEST50"))
    Else
        'begin with r=1 on a new worksheet
        Set ws = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=wb.Worksheets.Count)
        r = 1
        Call WriteData(ws, r, "TEST50,LTEST50")
    End If

 rcd.MoveNext

 Loop Until rcd.EOF

End Sub
Sub WriteData(ws as Object, r as Long, strData as String)
    With ws.Range("A" & r & ":B" & r)
        .Value = Split(strData, ",")
    End With
End Sub
Function CreateExcelFile() As Object
Dim xlApp as Object
Dim ret as Object

On Error Resume Next
Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
On Error GoTo 0

Set ret = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
Do Until ret.Worksheets.Count = 1
    ret.Worksheets(ret.Worksheets.Count).Delete
Loop

Set CreateExcelFile = ret
End Function
```